# ValueError: Worksheet index 2 is invalid, 2 worksheets found. There are 4 worksheets PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
Crime_NorthEast = pd.read_excel('CrimeStats.xlsx', sheet_name=2)
```

I get an error that only two sheets exist. Basically, I just added to the spreadsheet and had two sheets. I can't get my code to acknowledge the two new sheets.

I tried:

- Restarting Google Collab
- Checking Drive for a potential copy (none found)
- Checked I uploaded the correct version - 100% correct

```
upload_dataset = files.upload()
```

I used this method to upload the document.

Comment: In Python, indexes start from 0. The second sheet should be loaded using `sheet_name=1`. Did you try that?

Comment: I know that. I am trying to load the third and fourth sheets. Being told there are only two sheets though (there are definitely 4 sheets)